# программа на питоне выдает неверный ответ

Tags: python

решала следующую задачу:

> Василию очень нравится клеточный автомат «Game of life», поэтому он
> решил попробовать придумать что-то подобное. Для простоты, Василий
> решил определить свой клеточный автомат на массиве из n  ячеек, каждый
> элемент которого может быть в живом или неживом состоянии.
>
> Эволюция массива в клеточном автомате Василия происходит итеративно
> следующим образом:
>
> Если у неживого элемента есть ровно 1  живой сосед в текущем состоянии
> массива, то на следующей итерации он станет живым. Соседями для
> элемента на позиции i  являются элементы на позициях i−1  и i+1 , если
> соседа на такой позиции не существует, то считается, что он мертв.
> Василий — гуманист, поэтому все живые элементы в его автомате остаются
> живыми. Смотрите секцию примечание для примеров эволюции.
>
> Вам дано некоторое начальное состояние всех элементов, и вам нужно
> помочь Василию определить, каким будет состояние массива через m
> итераций эволюции.

Входные данные

> Во входных данных находятся несколько наборов входных данных. В первой
> строке находится одно целое число t  (1≤t≤103 ) — количество наборов
> входных данных. Далее следуют наборы входных данных.
>
> Первая строка набора входных данных содержит два целых числа n  и m
> (2≤n≤103,1≤m≤109 ) — количество ячеек в массиве и количество итераций.
>
> Вторая строка набора входных данных содержит строку длины n  из «0» и
> «1» — описание начального состояния. «1» обозначает живую клетку, а
> «0» — неживую.
>
> Гарантируется, что сумма значений n  по всем наборам входных данных не
> превосходит 104 .

Выходные данные

> Для каждого набора входных данных выведите строку из n  символов «0» и
> «1» — состояние массива через m  итераций эволюции.

Пример

Входные данные

```
4
11 3
01000000001
10 2
0110100101
5 2
10101
3 100
000
```

Выходные данные

```
11111001111
1110111101
10101
000
```

Написала по ней код, но он выдает неверный ответ, помогите пожалуйста исправить!!! Мой код:

```
n=int(input())
a=["1"]
b=["0"]
for i in range(n):
    kol, it=map(int, input().split(" "))
    st=input()
    st=st+"0"
    st=list(st)
    q=[]
    for j in range(len(st)):
        if j!=0:
            if st[0]=="0":
                if (st[j-1]=="1" and st[j+1]=="0") or (st[j-1]=="0" and ast[j+1]=="1"):
                    q.append(a)
                else:
                    q.append(b)
            else:
                q.append(a)
        elif j==0:
            if st[j]=="0":
                if st[j+1]=="1":
                    q.append(a)
                else:
                    q.append(b)
            else:
                q.append(a)
        elif j==len(st)-1:
            if st[j]=="0":
                if st[j-1]=="1":
                    q.append(a)
                else:
                    q.append(b)
            else:
                q.append(a)
        st=q
        q=[]
print(st)
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь:)

Comment: Приведите входные данные, чтобы любой желающий помочь сразу смог с ними работать, а не придумывать свое. И пояснение какой был ожидаемый результат, а какой у вас (кнопка [edit])

Comment: я же написала входные и выходные данные

Comment: Да, не увидел в полотне текста. Отформатировал вопрос

Comment: Не нужно дублировать один и тот же вопрос несколько раз

Answer (score 0):

```
t = int(input())
for _ in range(t):
    n, m = map(int, input().split())
    state = input().strip()
    state = list(map(int, state))
    
    for _ in range(m):
        new_state = [0]*n
        for i in range(n):
            count = 0
            if i > 0 and state[i-1] == 1:
                count += 1
            if i < n-1 and state[i+1] == 1:
                count += 1
            if count == 1:
                new_state[i] = 1
            elif count == 2 and state[i] == 1:
                new_state[i] = 1
        state = new_state
    
    print(''.join(map(str, state)))
```

Сначала мы считываем количество тестовых случаев `t`. Затем для каждого тестового случая мы считываем количество ячеек `n`, количество итераций `m` и начальное состояние массива `state`. Затем мы преобразуем строку `state` в список state из целых чисел `0` и `1`.

Далее мы выполняем цикл `for` для `m` итераций. На каждой итерации мы создаем новый список `new_state` из нулей длиной `n`. Затем мы выполняем еще один цикл `for` для каждого элемента `i` в `state`. Для каждого элемента мы проверяем его соседей слева и справа и подсчитываем количество живых соседей `count`. Если `count` равен `1`, то элемент становится живым в новом состоянии `new_state`. Если count равен `2` и элемент уже был живым, то он остается живым в новом состоянии. После завершения внутреннего цикла мы присваиваем переменной `state` значение `new_state`.

Наконец, мы выводим конечное состояние `state` в виде строки из `0` и `1`, используя метод `join()` для объединения элементов списка `state` в одну строку.

Comment: но ваша программа дает неверный ответ...

Comment: `но ваша программа дает неверный ответ` - это поделие ChatGPT

Answer (score 0):

Доработал ваш код, см. комментарии

```
data = """4
11 3
01000000001
10 2
0110100101
5 2
10101
3 100
000""".split('\n')


def input(): # чтобы не вводить руками данные
    global data
    return data.pop(0)


n = int(input())
a = "1" # список не нужен
b = "0" # список не нужен
for i in range(n):
    kol, it = map(int, input().split(" "))
    st = input()
    # st=st+"0" - лишнее
    st = list(st)

    for k in range(it): # забыли цикл с итерациями
        q = [] # перенести сюда
        for j in range(kol):
            if 0 < j < kol - 1: # здесь так
                if st[j] == "0":
                    if (st[j - 1] == "1" and st[j + 1] == "0") or (st[j - 1] == "0" and st[j + 1] == "1"):
                        q.append(a)
                    else:
                        q.append(b)
                else:
                    q.append(a)
            elif j == 0:
                if st[j] == "0":
                    if st[j + 1] == "1":
                        q.append(a)
                    else:
                        q.append(b)
                else:
                    q.append(a)
            elif j == kol - 1:
                if st[j] == "0":
                    if st[j - 1] == "1":
                        q.append(a)
                    else:
                        q.append(b)
                else:
                    q.append(a)
        st = q
        # q=[] - лишнее
    print(''.join(st))
```

```
11111001111
1110111101
10101
000
```